# React LocalStorage item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I want to do a type of authorization in react, but I ran into a problem when I add a token in one component, the 2nd does not see it, but sees it only after reloading the application.
How can this be corrected in the react?

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
const Login = () => {
 const handleLogin = () => {
      console.log( localStorage.getItem('token'));
      localStorage.setItem('token', 'token');
 }




 return (
      <div>
           <header className="">
                <ul>
                     <li><NavLink to="/main" activeClassName={'active-link'}>Home</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
           </header>
           <button onClick={handleLogin}>login</button>
      </div>
 );
 };

    export default Login;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {Route,Redirect,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from "./pages/login";
import Logout from "./pages/logout";
import Main from "./pages/main";
import ErrorPage from "./pages/error";

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>ore</div>
      <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/">
                <Redirect to="/login" />
           </Route>
           {
                localStorage.getItem('token') ?  <Route path="/main"  component={Main} /> : null
           }
           <Route path="/login"  component={Login} />
           <Route path="/portfolio"  component={Logout} />
           <Route path="/error" exact component={ErrorPage} />
           <Redirect to={'/error'}  />

      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The localStorage.getItem is no State, so it won't take effect before reloading.
Use Redux or some reducer to store tokens temporarily and then save them to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the useEffect and useState into your app.js

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState([]);
  const tokenFromLogin = localStorage.getItem("token");

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(tokenFromLogin);
  }, [jwt]);
```

Comment: from  Redux or in more detail?